# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis

first time posting a question so go easy on me.

I found some code online that i am trying to implement myself though i keep coming across this error

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

the code is as follows:

```
for i,feats,label in enumerate(testfeats):
        refsets[label].add(i)
        observed = classifier.classify(feats)
        testsets[observed].add(i)
```

If you can help me out this would be great :)

Answer (score 8):

To add to timgeb's answer, the solution is to change the header of your for loop:

```py
    for i, (feats, label) in enumerate(testfeats):
        ...
```

which is the same as:

```py
    for i, itemValue in enumerate(testfeats):
        feats, label = itemValue
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`enumerate` gives your an iterator over `(index, value)` tuples which are always of length two.

You are trying to unpack each two-value tuple into three names (`i`, `feats`, `label`) which must fail because of the mismatch of values in the tuple and number of names you are trying to assign.

Answer (score 2):

In much simple words, ***enumerate()*** return only two value, whereas you are expecting three.
i.e expected 3, received 2 :)